# The layer cannot be added to the map

Tags: arcgis-online, arcgis-online-webmap

Sometimes ArcGIS Online application keeps showing the popup that several layers cannot be added to the map. This happens randomly, let's say for 3 months it has happened 3 times. And it is automatically fixed the next day. The application has more than 100 layers, and when I refresh it the layers that cant be added are not always the same.
I wonder if this is an AGOL issue or I have to take any action to prevent it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution for this issue is to contact support.

Comment: I don't see any reason why this comment was downvoted by someone. It would certainly be best to contact the support team for ArcGIS Online for assistance with troubleshooting this issue. They have had many bugs in the past and they do fix them when highlighted so raising a My Esri ticket is the best bet.